# Error execution Python script from php in Apache2

Tags: php, python, apache2

I'm creating a web application managed with apache2, the problem I'm trying to solve is running a python script using php, I'm attaching my code:

```
PHP CODE:

<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/yoloface-master/showInWeb.py");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

```
PYTHON CODE

#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import hashlib, os, sys, cv2, PIL, subprocess, glob, numpy, django, random
from PIL import Image
import shutil



def showInWeb():

    pathYolo = 'yoloface-master/'
    os.chdir(pathYolo)
    photo = random.choice(os.listdir("../Database/ARCHIVIOIMAGO"))
    path = '../Database/ARCHIVIOIMAGO/'
    print(photo)
    shutil.rmtree('outputs/')
    processPhoto = path + photo
    command_line = ('python3.6', 'yoloface.py', '--image', processPhoto, '--output-dir', 'outputs/')
    print(subprocess.run(command_line))

showInWeb();
```

As IDE I'm using pyCharm, and if I run the same command line in the pyCharm terminal (I'm not in a virtual environment) the program works without problems, however if I run it through the php script I get an error like "No Module Named cv2 ", this makes me guess that php is using a different version.
I read on the internet that a possible solution was to place "sudo" on the command line like:

`sudo /usr/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/yoloface-master/showInWeb.py`

But I get this error:

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

How can I do?